# Speakers to 3.5mm jack?

Tags: hardware, speakers

wasnt sure whether this was better-suited to the Electronics stackexchange. If so please could you migrate it there?

I have just moved into a much smaller flat and due to the size, I can't fit my rather large speakers in there.

Is there any way I can get my mixer (picture) to output to my other (smaller) speakers, which use a single 3.5mm jack??

I'm pretty sure its not as simple as just plugging one of these in: http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?hl=en&client=firefox-a&q=speaker+cable+to+3.5mm+jack&cid=5277653965180184999&ei=DnU0TZq7GYit-AagrsXoDQ&sa=title&ved=0CAcQ8wIwADgA#p but who knows.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it *is* just that simple.  If your speakers have a 3.5mm jack as input, they are expecting a headphone-level signal such as an iPod or other PMP output... which is pretty much what's on your mixer's RCA jacks.

Comment: @rmx, get what you need here:  http://www.monoprice.com/products/subdepartment.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10218  Far cheaper than your link.

Comment: In the end I went with this one: http://www.amazon.co.uk/3-5mm-Stereo-Socket-Phono-Plugs/dp/B0009N1MV4/ref=pd_cp_ce_0